# Apache Airflow CLI command -'list-runs' not working without Dag_id

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, airflow, command-line-interface

Building AWS lambda function that connect with Manage Apache airflow of AWS and get the info of all runs for all dag.

Initially, I tried command as below :

```
mwaa_cli_command=f'dags list-runs --dag dag_name'
above command works but not below one :
mwaa_cli_command=f'dags list-runs'
```

Please guide me on this. Is this airflow list-runs CLI command not works for all the dags?